# FluentValidation NotEmpty message is not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

For example, FluentValidation validates an empty email address that a user inputs.

I chained two functions but it skips the `.NotEmpty().WithMessage()` and jumps to the next which is `EmailAddress().WithMessage()`.

```
RuleFor(r => r.EmailAddress)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email address is required.")
                .EmailAddress().WithMessage("Email address is not valid.");
```

Why is that the error message is `"Email address is not valid."` while the first in chain is `"Email address is required."`?

Answer (score 5):

This is because the last condition is always verified, even if the first rule fails. Try setting the `CascadeMode`, as described in [the documentation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Cascade), like this:

```
RuleFor(r => r.EmailAddress)
    .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
    .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email address is required.")
    .EmailAddress().WithMessage("Email address is not valid.");
```